# Flutter: Why are navigators being reset when added to tree?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to understand why my instances of `Navigator` are being reset when I add them to the UI tree. Currently I have a view that looks like this:

```dart
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  HomeView({this.title});
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState(title: title);
}

class ViewData {
  Widget Function() _create;
  Widget _cache;

  Widget get view {
    if (_cache == null) {
      _cache = Navigator(
          key: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return _create();
                },
                settings: settings);
          });
    }
    return _cache;
  }

  ViewData(this._create);
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  String title;
  int _viewIndex = 0;
  final List<ViewData> _views = [
    ViewData(() => TodayView()),
    ViewData(() => RecordView()),
    ViewData(() => MoreView(key: GlobalKey())),
  ];

  // Constructor
  _HomeViewState({this.title});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _viewIndex,
        children: _views.map((view) => view.view).toList(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() => _viewIndex = index);
        },
        currentIndex: _viewIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm), label: "TODAY"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.wysiwyg), label: "WORK RECORD"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz), label: "MORE"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works in that when I execute a `.push(...)` to add a view to one of my `Navigator` instances, then changes tabs, then change back, the navigator stack is as I left it with the pushed view visible.

But if I remove the `IndexedStack` from the `build(...)` function like this:

```dart
      body: _views[_viewIndex].view,
```

Then when I switch back to a tab where I've pushed a new view, the navigator is reset back to the root widget.

I would have thought that because I'm caching the navigators in a list news ones would not be built, so I'm guessing that this is something to do with the lifecycle of a widget when it's added to the tree.

The reason I don't want to use an `IndexedStack` is that it loads all the widgets up front and some will involve database queries, so I'd rather lazy load. I figure I can change the widgets somehow so they lazy load, but I'd rather just not load them at all until the user switches to them.

Can anyone clarify the lifecycle of when a widget is removed and added back to the UI tree? And if there are any other approaches that might work better at preserving each navigator's stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to assign a unique global key to each navigator and also use the `IndexedStack` to ensure the navigators aren't reset by removing and re-adding them to the UI.